# Derivative of anonymous functions without defining symbolic variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, derivative, function-handle

Consider the following code:

```
f = @(x) x.^2;
```

Is it possible to get the derivative of the function handle `f` as another function handle, without defining a symbolic variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, to obtain a derivative function you need to use the Symbolic toolbox.

But you can get an approximation (finite difference approximation) by creating a function as follows:

```
f = @(x) x.^2;
d = 1e-6;
df = @(x) (f(x+d)-f(x))/d;
```

`d` here determines precision of the approximation. If you make it too small, you'll end up in the floating-point rounding error domain, so be careful!

Testing:

```
x = -2:0.01:2;
max(abs(df(x) - 2*x))  % returns 1.0006e-06
```

Comment: Or even better, use higher order schemes, or at least using a central difference `@(x)  (f(x+d)-f(x-d))/(2*d)` - allowing you increased accuracy for the same `d`. This is the correct approach though